# IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to define a variable Ytest which has the 10 column entries or the label entries from my excel sheet.

```
names = ["Variable1","Variable2","Variable3","Variable4","Variable5","Variable6","Variable7","Variable8","Variable9","label"]
filename = 'C:/Users/qwert/test.csv'
dataframe = read_csv(filename, names=names)
dataframe.head(6)
array = dataframe.values
array.shape
(16259, 10)

X_train= array[0:1162,0:9]
X_train.shape
(1162, 9)

X_test= array[1163:2300,0:9]
X_test.shape
(1137, 9)

y_test=array[1163:2300,10]
y_test.shape
```

But it gives me error

```
IndexError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-210-d6922be9e642> in <module>() 1 #y_test=array[1163:2300,0:10] ----> 2 y_test=array[1163:2300,10] 3 y_test.shape IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10
```

Am I missing something here ? I basically wanted all my labels which are in 10 column of my excel to be in y_test

Comment: The indices run 0-9; index 10 would be the 11th position.

Comment: Can you include a few lines from the test.csv file you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Column 10 in Excel would be indexed as column 9 in Python, since the indexing begins from 0. So what the error is saying is that since you have 10 columns, you can only call them from 0 to 9, but calling index = 10 is like calling the 11th column, and so it throws an error.

If you need Column 10 from Excel, you should make it `y_test=array[1163:2300, 9]`.